# Trying to build a menu system with an OLED and ESP32

Tags: c++, esp32

I'm working on a personal project, involving an ESP32-S2, OLED (SH1106) and generic button encoder.
Right now I'm at a stage where I want to put together a simple menu system that's just 3 levels deep.

```
Main Menu
  Sub Menu 1
    Preset1
    Preset2
    Preset3
    .
    .
    .
  Sub Menu 2
    Number Selector
```

Found a library that partially helps me to put together what I wanted. [OLEDDisplayUi](https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-oled-ssd1306/tree/master) specifically, single page options with an indicator above.

I'm fairly new to C++ so I might have tried to bite more than I can chew.
This is my code so far

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SH1106Wire.h"
#include "AiEsp32RotaryEncoder.h"
#include "OLEDDisplayUi.h"
#include "images.h"

#define ROTARY_ENCODER_A_PIN 7
#define ROTARY_ENCODER_B_PIN 5
#define ROTARY_ENCODER_BUTTON_PIN 3
#define ROTARY_ENCODER_STEPS 4

AiEsp32RotaryEncoder rotaryEncoder = AiEsp32RotaryEncoder(ROTARY_ENCODER_A_PIN, ROTARY_ENCODER_B_PIN, ROTARY_ENCODER_BUTTON_PIN, -1, ROTARY_ENCODER_STEPS);
SH1106Wire display(0x3c, 8, 9);
OLEDDisplayUi ui ( &display );

unsigned long shortPressAfterMiliseconds = 50;
unsigned long longPressAfterMiliseconds = 600;

void shortPress() {
  Serial.println("Button SHORT press");
  Serial.println(ui.getUiState()->frameState);
}

void longPress() {
  Serial.println("Button LONG press");
}

void IRAM_ATTR readEncoderISR() {
  rotaryEncoder.readEncoder_ISR();
}

void encoderButton() {
  static unsigned long lastTimeButtonDown = 0;
  static bool wasButtonDown = false;
  static bool wasLong = false;
  bool isEncoderButtonDown = rotaryEncoder.isEncoderButtonDown();

  if ( isEncoderButtonDown ) {
    if ( !wasButtonDown ) {
      lastTimeButtonDown = millis();
      wasButtonDown = true;
    }

    if ( !wasLong ) {
      if ( millis() - lastTimeButtonDown >= longPressAfterMiliseconds ) {
        longPress();
        wasLong = true;
      }
    }

    return;
  }
  
  if ( wasButtonDown && !wasLong ) {
    if ( millis() - lastTimeButtonDown >= shortPressAfterMiliseconds ) {
      shortPress();
      wasLong = false;
    }
  }

  wasButtonDown = false;
  wasLong = false;
}

void encoderLoop() {
  if (rotaryEncoder.encoderChanged()) {
    static int8_t prev = 0;
    int8_t curr = rotaryEncoder.readEncoder();
    if ( curr > prev ) {
      ui.nextFrame();
    } else if ( curr < prev ) {
      ui.previousFrame();
    }
    prev = rotaryEncoder.readEncoder();
  }
  encoderButton();
}

void frame1(OLEDDisplay *display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {
  display->setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
  display->setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display->drawString(64 + x, 19 + y, "Presets");
}

void frame2(OLEDDisplay *display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {
  display->setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
  display->setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display->drawString(64 + x, 19 + y, "Precise");
}

FrameCallback frames[] = { frame1, frame2 };
int frameCount = 2;

void setupMainMenu() {
  ui.setTargetFPS(60);
  ui.setActiveSymbol(activeSymbol);
  ui.setInactiveSymbol(inactiveSymbol);
  ui.setIndicatorPosition(TOP);
  ui.setIndicatorDirection(LEFT_RIGHT);
  ui.setFrameAnimation(SLIDE_LEFT);
  ui.setFrames(frames, frameCount);
  ui.disableAutoTransition();
  ui.setTimePerTransition(60);
  ui.init();
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  pinMode(ROTARY_ENCODER_A_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ROTARY_ENCODER_B_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  rotaryEncoder.begin();
  rotaryEncoder.setup(readEncoderISR);
  rotaryEncoder.setAcceleration(80);

  setupMainMenu();

  display.flipScreenVertically();
}


void loop() {
  encoderLoop();
  ui.update();
}
```

Also a [Wokwi](https://wokwi.com/projects/391334033972591617) link.

Idea is to rotate the encoder to select a frame, short press to move down a submenu, long press to move up.
I tried messing around with Classes and Objects, migrating frame functions to achive a modular system. Primarily because the number of Presets can vary depending on the situation. Everything else is fairly static.
My knowledge on C++ is still limited, and some examples or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's the actual question?

Comment: Thank you. How could I proceed into putting together the menu system I mentioned?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).